# How can I make a program start at a higher priority?

Tags: process-priority

I'd like to set my pulseeffects to start  up at a higher priority automatically after booting up the pc. It works as a workaround for couple small issues but setting it manually every time starts to get annoying.

Answer (score 0):

By using `nice`, see `man nice;man renice`. Something like (I haven't tried exactly this):

```
sudo nice -n -1 sudo -u $USER /path/to/pulseeffects
```